# How to send an image file over a HttpServer in Dart?

Tags: dart

I am writing a web server application using Dart.

How do I send an image file through a HttpServer to the browser?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you receive a request for an image, send a header to state the content type and length, and then the file contents.

```js
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

  HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8080).then((server) {
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {

        File image = new File("chicken.jpeg");
        image.readAsBytes().then(
            (raw){
              request.response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
              request.response.headers.set('Content-Length', raw.length);
              request.response.add(raw);
              request.response.close();
              });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: how do you send text from sever to client.